# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Caffe install

Tags: python, caffe

I am trying to install caffe on my windows, I have correctly copy caffe lib under my python site-packages folder and installed protobuf. But I still get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/sworr/Desktop/caffe-ssd/examples/ssd/score_ssd_pascal.py", line 2, in <module>
    import caffe
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\caffe\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\caffe\pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am using Anaconda 4.0.0 64-bit. Please kindly help.

Comment: I am using windows 10.

Comment: Make sure that the caffe lib's name is `_caffe.pyd` instead of `_caffe.dll` so that it will be recognized by python.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this probkem by installing caffe using VS 2015 + CUDA 8.0 + Nvidia Titan X (pascal) by following the [tutorial](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) given by BLVC.

I think the solution to this issue is building the 'runtest' programs first.

```
cmake --build . --config %CMAKE_CONFIGURATION% --target install
```

I am using Anaconda 4.1.12 (64-bit) and windows 7 platform.

There also other matters needs attention:

1. Remember to add the path of dependencies to your PATH environment.

   ```
   CAFFE_DEPENDENCIES=%CAFFE_ROOT%\scripts\libraries
   PATH=%PATH%;%CAFFE_ROOT%\scripts\libraries;%CAFFE_DEPENDENCIES%\bin;%CAFFE_DEPENDENCIES%\lib;%CAFFE_DEPENDENCIES%\x64\vc14\bin
   ```
2. Remember to put cudnn library to cuda installation path.
3. After build the runtest program, copy the caffe package to the Anaconda's site-package path:
   copy `%CAFE_ROOT%\python\caffe` to `%ANACONDA2_ROOT%\Lib\site-packages\`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.
Please do not add caffe lib to site packages. It does not require. Please follow the [BLVC](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) installation guide when building the Caffe. Caffe will automatically download related dependencies and copy them to C:/Users/name/.caffe.

When you run the `build_win.cmd`, it will use those dependencies and create caffe lib inside the build directory.